Sub-/superscript size difference between newtxmath and txfonts
When comparing newtxmath and txfonts, the most striking difference I’ve noticed is that subscripts and superscripts take up much more space with newtxmath than with txfonts, in both glyph size and spacing. While this is probably intended since the description of the newtx packages is “Alternative uses of the TX fonts, with improved metrics”, I just wanted to ask here to make sure that this is how it’s supposed to be. The reasons why I’m slightly skeptical are that

Only the subscripts and superscripts have different glyph sizes, while “normal” text is unaffected,
I couldn’t find any mention of this in the newtx documentation, which otherwise extensively lists numerous minute differences between these fonts and other/older versions,
the effect seems more pronounced using the mnras class (which is how I came across this), which may be doing some funky font size setup?

The only place where I’ve found any reference to this difference is in the question “packages times(-itsc), txfonts, newtxtext/newtxmath, and mathptmx: relation and interactions”, although none of the answers address that specific point.
For reference, this is what I get with the following example:
\documentclass{mnras}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
% choose one
%\usepackage{txfonts}
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
& x^{abc}
\\
& y^{123}
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}

txfonts:

newtxmath:


I suggest you edit your example using article class because the same can be observed with it.

@user691586 With article, I’m finding a much smaller difference (consistent with your answer), but with mnras, the difference in height is much larger, around 22% (see my comment on your answer). I wouldn’t have taken much notice of a 4% difference, but 22% is something else!

Yes I overlooked that mnras uses 9pt as normal size and this makes the newtx settings even more dramatically divergent from what one sees with txfonts, as we are in 9pt normal ambient font size. and not 10pt.  In place of a 4.3% increase in height it is a near to 22% increase as you reported.  Sorry for not checking too closely but mnras was not installed on my system originally.  See edited answer.

important edit
In the OP case with mnras class an important fact is that basically it makes the normal size be 9pt i.e. the equivalent of \small in article class.  But here the distortion induced by newtx \DeclareMathSizes is even larger because we have to compare original \DeclareMathSizes{9}{9}{6}{5} with newtx \DeclareMathSizes{9}{9}{7.3}{5.5} so the size of subscripts is 6pt with txfonts but 7.3pt with newtx, i.e. more than 21% larger (21.666666...%).
A "fix" (untested) could be to add \DeclareMathSizes{9}{9}{6}{5} to the document preamble.
original answer
File newtxmath.sty does the following declarations:
\def\defaultscriptratio{.73} % default is .7
\def\defaultscriptscriptratio{.55} % default is .5
\DeclareMathSizes{5}    {5.5}    {5.5}    {5.5}
\DeclareMathSizes{6}    {6.5}    {5.5}    {5.5}
\DeclareMathSizes{7}    {7.3}    {5.5}    {5.5}
\DeclareMathSizes{8}    {8}    {6.2}    {5.5}
\DeclareMathSizes{9}    {9}    {7.3}    {5.5}
\DeclareMathSizes{10}   {10}   {7.3}  {5.5} 
\DeclareMathSizes{10.95}{10.95}{8}    {6.1}
\DeclareMathSizes{11}   {10.95}{8}    {6.1}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}   {12}   {8.8}    {6.6}
\DeclareMathSizes{14.4} {14.4} {10.5}   {7.9}
\DeclareMathSizes{17.28}{17.28}{12.5}   {9.4}
\DeclareMathSizes{20.74}{20.74}{16.1} {11.4}
\DeclareMathSizes{24.88}{24.88}{18.2}{13.7}

whereas loading txfonts does not lead to usge of \DeclareMathSizes.  So with article class,  this means the LaTeX default from fontmath.ltx are used which are:
 \DeclareMathSizes{5}{5}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{6}{6}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{7}{7}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{8}{8}{6}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{9}{9}{6}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{7}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{8}{6}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xiipt}{\@xiipt}{8}{6}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xpt}{7}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xviipt}{\@xviipt}{\@xiipt}{\@xpt}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xxpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xiipt}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xxvpt}{\@xxvpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xviipt}

and one finds also in the latex kernel:
\def\defaultscriptratio{.7}
\def\defaultscriptscriptratio{.5}

This is surely main cause for the observed size differences. And there may be a problem of non-continuous scaling (the kind of things fix-cm handles for legacy Computer Modern fonts) but I have not checked further, so saying this hypothetically and it may not be the case.

Here is output of 
\sbox0{$\scriptstyle abc$}ht=\the\ht0\ dp=\the\dp0\ wd=\the\wd0


with txfonts: ht=4.72499pt dp=0.05249pt wd=10.108pt.
with newtxmath: ht=4.92749pt dp=0.05473pt wd=13.2604pt.
with newtxmath + \DeclareMathSizes{10}{10}{7}{5} in the preamble: ht=4.72499pt dp=0.05249pt wd=12.71544pt.

and (Python interactive):
>>> 4.92749/4.72499
1.0428572335602826
>>> 7.3/7
1.042857142857143

so it is logical.  It may be that there is also a perception effect which increases the 4.29% difference.

I have also done the measurements using mnras class and the results are exactly identical with those using article class with newtxtt, newtxmath, and I don't see any visual difference.  I checked quickly in mnras.cls source code and all I can find is that it redeclares the symbols font in bold math versino to be the legacy one but this is probably overwritten by newtxmath and it  defines a boldsymbols font and some \balpha symbolds (and \largerm and \largeital commands) but all of this appears to be irrelevant here.

I’m not getting the same numbers as you with mnras and txfonts: ht=4.04999pt dp=0.045pt wd=8.664pt, i. e. 4.92749/4.04999 = 1.2166672016 – about a 22% difference! Could you check again and/or send some more details about your environment? I used pdflatex and TeX Live 2024.

@Socob Indeed you are right! I had not tested mnras+  txfonts. I too get  ht=4.04999pt dp=0.045pt wd=8.664pt. I guess an update to my answer is really needed, but I can't now and perhaps for some time investigate the root cause. I must have looked too superficially at mnras.cls and did not all anticipate such a dramatic result.

@Socob mnras.cls makes \normalsize use 9pt, i.e. it is like \small with article.cls. So we have to compare the default \DeclareMathSizes{9}{9}{6}{5} with newtx \DeclareMathSizes{9}{9}{7.3}{5.5} and we find the whopping 7.3/6=1.2166666... of your comment...

@Socob See edited answer.  The \DeclareMathSizes{9}{9}{7.3}{5.5}  of newtx looks a abit anomalous. Maybe report to newtx maintainer?  Naively one would have expected something  like {9}{9}{6.57}{4.95} or not too different.  This would still make +10% larger subscripts but not +22%...

Thanks for looking into it again! Especially for confirming that this is (potentially) unexpected. I’ll try contacting Michael Sharpe (newtx maintainer).
